# How to prepare multiple physical sites with multiple variate for LSTM in Keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I have multiple physical sites, and each site with multiple variate, how can I prepare the inputs, for example,

10 sites,and each site have 1 main input:

- Water volume

and 2 secondary inputs:

- Temperature
- Rainfall

if I only use one site, the hyper-parameters is to define as follow:

- timesteps: lets say 10-days as a circle for observation
- input_dim: Water volume, Temperature, Rainfall
- batch_size: 32
  where it contains 10 days of 3 features in 32 batch size.

And My question is ​how can I prepare inputs of the **all 3 variate** form **all 10 sites** for LSTM?

Comment: can anyone give help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem description is quite confusing, i hope i got it right.

There are few things you need to confirm:

- What is your purpose: Which value do you want your model to estimate

So i will just assume you want to predict the Water volume, then there are some hyper-parameters you need to define:

- timesteps: lets say 10-days as a circle for observation
- input_dim: features you have, in this case you have 2, Temperature and Rainfall
- batch_size: it depens on your data size
  then you will have keras style input (32, 10, 2), where it contains 10 days of 2 features in 32 batch size.

Comment: Thanks Merdan, I have edit my question, which make it more clear, hope your valuable suggestions